# Использование Dragon SDK в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Пытаюсь реализовать программу для преобразования **речи в текст**. В помощники взял Dragon SDK. Раньше никогда не сталкивался с этой библиотекой и подобных вещей не программировал. Тут столько всякого. А мне нужно перевести звук в текст, а не текст в звук. Как-то запутался во всем этом разнообразии. Какие именно классы тут отвечают за преобразование звука? Преобразование нужно сделать немецкой речи. Я на сайте библиотеки зарегистрировался и получил уже ID и key, правда еще не знаю куда их вставлять.

Comment: Уважаемый, вы гуглить не пробовали? Вот например я нагуглил http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/RecognizerSample.html 
В крайнем случае можно написать разрвбам обычно они отвечают на интересные вопросы.

Comment: Да спасибо. Я тоже наткнулся на эту статью и работаю над ней. Я думал что у Apple будут какие-то родные инструменты по этой части. По всей вероятности их нет. Для Siri видимо сами тоже пользуются сторонними разработками.